# Read text file from web

Tags: android, file

I recover my text file distant, my text contains number one "1". I tried to convert my text "1"(char)to int, but it is giving error. I used method `Integer.parseInt(String)`

this is my code:
MainActivity.java

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

PackageInfo pinfo;
String contentFichier;
TextView txt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recoverContentTextFile();

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    try {
        pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //Here error
    int i = Integer.parseInt(contentFichier);


}


public void recoverContentTextFile() {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String path ="my_url_text_file";
            URL u = null;
            try {
                u = new URL(path);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.connect();
                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
                bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        contentFichier = bo.toString();
                        try {
                            bo.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }.start();
}

}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: What error is it? Is it a NumberFormatException? If yes, print out the String before the error and see if it's a valid number.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not a good idea at all to use threads in the way you're implementing in your method `recoverContextTextFile`. What happens if the user rotate the device and the petition takes 8 minutes to complete? You have created a memory leak!

The second thing as you have created a thread the variable `contentFichier` will be sometimes null (because `recoverContextTextFile` does create a thread) and calling the `Integer.parseInt(contentFichier);`will raise an Exception.

For this case I think that it's better to use an AsyncTask ([which I highly dislike](http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/) and taking care of not leaking the activity when rotation occurs), do the petition in the `onBackground` method and in the method `onPostExecute` call the `Integer.parseInt(contentFichier);`.

I [recommend reading this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) by Lars Vogel as it explains a lot about background processing.

Comment: I would disagree, you can solve the memory leak with a WeakReference and making the AsyncTask static. However, no, it does not solve all problems, and more work would be needed to make it work like a charm.

Comment: Yeah but IMHO I prefer to use other alternatives like JobPriority Queue for background processing (but it has its own shortcomings too). For this simple case it's better to use the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is probably that you are trying to convert the String before the thread has finished. And also, Android has a better way than Threads to handle most (simple) background tasks, the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You could do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    PackageInfo pinfo;
    String contentFichier;
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Setup your activity here

        new ContentFetcher().execute("http://......");

    }

    private class ContentFetcher extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String stringResponse = null;

            try{
                HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(params[0]));
                stringResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            return stringResponse;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //DO something with the response here - maybe test if the s variable is indeed an integer
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);

        }
    }
}
```

To execute the task run:

```
new ContentFetcher().execute("http://whatever.com/mytext.txt");
```

Comment: Where I do this class?

Comment: Put it in your MainActivity, replace your recoverContentTextFile  method with this class.

Comment: I did not understand!

Comment: See updated answer, replace new HttpGet("") with new HttpGet(params[0])

Comment: The data you're getting appears to contain a "?", check if this is the case and fix it on the server. If this is not an option do something like `s.replaceAll("?", "");`

Answer (score 0):

Add log statement to show the value of the `contentFichier`:

```
Log.i("contentFichier", "["+contentFichier+"]"
```

You will see which content is being parsed. Maybe there is a whitespace on the beginning or the end. Also the server may be returning wrong value or empty string.

Comment: O-ops, then use AsyncTask as proposed by @Squeazer